# zf2 Album with doctrine

Tags: doctrine, zend-framework2

I installed doctrine and this is working with zfcUser. Now I want install the module Album and I getting the follwoing error:

A 404 error occurred
Page not found.
The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class.

Controller:
album/album(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: album/album)
No Exception available

Can somebody provide my an solution?

The setup is comming from: http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/01/using-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may not have loaded the module in your /config/application.config.php

Should look something like this;

```
<?php
return array(
// This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
'modules' => array(
'Application',
'DoctrineModule',
'DoctrineORMModule',
'Album',

),

// etc ...
```

BTW, I am new to ZF2 and doctrine also - I found this example of the album module using doctrine that actually works and it was a great help to get started ( https://github.com/shanethehat/zf2-doctrine-tutorial )